# Storyshot for Storybook/Vue broken with error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, webpack-4, storybook, storyshots

More detail is within [this ticket](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/4793).

Pasted here for what it looks at at this point:

> **Describe the bug**
>
> Massive cant resolve 'fs' came up with storyshot config after jest already configed and storybook was running correctly.
>
> **To Reproduce**
>
> Steps to reproduce the behavior:
>
> 1. git clone https://github.com/adamchenwei/boilerplate-webpack-babel-sass-storybook-vuejs
> 2. git checkout `broken/start-after-storyshot-setup`
> 3. npm install && npm run storybook
> 4. See error
>
> **Expected behavior**
>
> storyshot should not cause error prevent storybook run correctly
>
> **Screenshots**
>
> [image]
>
> **Code snippets**
>
> If applicable, add code samples to help explain your problem.
>
> **System:**
>
> - OS: MacOS
> - Device: Macbook Pro
> - Browser: NA
> - Framework: Vue
> - Addons:
>
>   ```
>   "@storybook/addon-storyshots": "^4.0.6",
>   "@storybook/vue": "^4.0.6",
>   ```

Additional info:

I attempted adding `node: { fs: 'empty' },` into Storybook's config, it will just cause other error than 'fs' not found one. So not really solving the issue.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: its a problem with the compatibility between libraries. not yet resolves, last tried two month ago

Comment: Hm yeah, I also found this issue: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/2898 :/

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding this to my `.storybook/main.js`:

```
webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      'fs': path.resolve(__dirname, 'fsMock.js')
    };
    return config
  }
```

Content of `.storybook/fsMock.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  readFileSync: () => 'mock',
}
```

More information:

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/4082#issuecomment-417329791